# Android studio skips the login page when user doesn't log out

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My mobile app needs a feature that from the splash screen when the user is still logged in it wont show the login page any more using shared preference. Here are my codes for references.

## Splash

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                Intent in = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
   }
}
```

## Loginpage(the one that will be skipped if user doesn't logs out)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstname);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);

    pref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = pref.getString("username", "");
    String password = pref.getString("password", "");

    if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals(""))) {
        postData.put("username", username);
        postData.put("password", password);
        authenticate(postData);
    }

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor = pref.edit();
            editor.clear();
            postData.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
            postData.put("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));
            editor.commit();
            authenticate(postData);
        }
    });

    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
private void authenticate(final HashMap<String, String> postData){
    PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
            new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    if (s.contains("renter")) {
                        // Login success, Save to prefs
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RenterTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();

                    } else if (s.contains("owner")) {
                        // Login success, Save to prefs
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OwnerTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    } else if (s.contains("-1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong username or password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/authenticate.php");
    task1.setEachExceptionsHandler(new EachExceptionsHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleIOException(IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Connect to Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleProtocolException(ProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Protocol Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleUnsupportedEncodingException(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encoding Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

> The classes that It'll be going are `OwnerTabs.java` or `RenterTabs.java`

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

In the login class where you're saving the username and password to the sharedpreferences, you should also save a boolean value *isLoggedIn*- **true** if the login is successful, and **false** if not.

Then, you can then put the `authenticate` method in your splash activity too and call it using the saved username and password values (if the boolean is true). You should rather extract the `authenticate` method to a separate class and call it from login as well as the signup.

If calling the `authenticate` method is not important if the user is already logged in, you can simply check the *isLoggedIn* in your splash activity and direct the user to Owner or Renter class.